# Sweetalert not appearing after success function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, bootstrap-4, sweetalert

Sweetalert warning seem to be working fine after clicking the delete button **but the alert inside ajax success function as confirmation does not appear on the page**

I'm really new in coding and i was following a tutorial in youtube about deleting a data from php database.

I think I did everything right and rechecked if there's a spelling or punctuation error or what but I couldnt figure out what it is. Please, help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.delete_product_btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).val();
        

        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this data!",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
          })
          .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "code.php",
                    data: {
                        'product_id':id,
                        'delete_product_btn': true
                    },

                    success: function (response) {
                        if(response == 200)
                        {
                            swal("Good job!", "Deleted successfully!", "success");

                        }
                        else if(response == 500)
                        {
                            swal("Error!", "Something went wrong!", "error");

                        }

                    }
                });
            } 
          });

    });

 });
```

Comment: `if(response == 200)` I think the bug is here. Console.log the response and see if you are comparing the right value. It can be `response.data`.

Comment: Unless your issue has something to do with PHP (PHP code not working), please remove that tag. If there are some issues with PHP, then please post that code and explain the issue (what happens, what suppose to happen etc)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: debug.... `console.log(response, response == 200, escape(response));`

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume that the code.php will return a value of "500" if record NOT deleted , and return a value of "200" if record is successfully deleted. (so after the delete action, either `echo "200";` or `echo "500";`)

Secondly, you should have the proper jquery.js script included (say placed at the top of the script)

In that case, both the two swal alerts should work, but if the code.php does not return either 500 or 200, then of course the 2nd swal alert will NOT be triggered. (this can be the root cause of the issue but since I cannot see your PHP code I cannot further comment, so make sure the code.php will return either 200 or 500)

So please try the following code :
(I've created a code.php which always `echo "200";`)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


Delete: 
<br>
<input type=button class="delete_product_btn" value="1">
<br>
<input type=button class="delete_product_btn" value="2">

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.delete_product_btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

var id = $(this).val();


swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {



   $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "code.php",
                    data: {
                        'product_id':id,
                        'delete_product_btn': true
                    },

                    success: function (response) {
                        if(response == 200)
                        {
                            swal("Good job!", "Deleted successfully!", "success");

                        }
                        else if(response == 500)
                        {
                            swal("Error!", "Something went wrong!", "error");

                        }

                    }
                });



  } else {
    swal("Delete action aborted!");
  }
});


   });

 });

</script>
```

You may try the above script in this fully working sandbox link:

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testso7Oct2022.html